# mysql , alias field with a point separator like postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

it's possible to have a field alias with a '.' like postgresql

Example:

```
`messages`.`text` AS `messages.text`
```

in

```
SELECT `channel`.`id`, `channel`.`name`, `messages`.`text` AS `messages.text`, FROM `channels` AS `channel` LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages` AS `messages` ON `channel`.`id` = `messages`.`channelId` WHERE `channel`.`id` = '1';
```

Comment: Is there a space between messages and . and . and text or is that just a quirk in the copy and paste?

Comment: @P.Salmon i ve formatted now well the code, there no espaces,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know that it's not possible to do that in mysql

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put the alias in quotes:

```
SELECT messages.text AS "messages.text" FROM messages;
```

However, "messages.text" will be just a string. You cannot use "messages.text" as a reference in other parts of the query.

Comment: yes i need a reference, so is not really possible... to get the value from the field?